# Slickgrid pagination with rest post request

Tags: slickgrid

I have a requirement of implementing pagination control to slickgrid. currently iam backbone collection to populate my slickgrid and using slickback to handle the pagination which works fine for the GET requests. Can you please let me know how to implement pagination for post request to the rest service where the service accepts JSON object along with page and perPage query parameters used for pagination. kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

take this is options for your requirement accordingly 
var options = {
                        columns: columns,
                        idProperty: 'ID',
                        showCheckboxes: false,
                        showDrillDown: false,
                        showGridSettings: true,
                        showFilter: false,
                        enableColumnReorder: false,
                        pagingMode: PagingModes.PagerClientSide,
                        showFooter: true,
                        savePersonalization: false,
                        pageSize: 15,
                        autoHeight: true,
                        forceFitColumns: true,
                        dataset: data
                    };